# Confluence 8.0 plugin, searchFilter deprecated / removed

Tags: java, maven, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

With Confluence Version 8.0 the:

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.searchfilter.SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter;
```

has been removed and the docs say:

```
com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.searchfilter (use the equivalent class that extends SearchQuery in 8.0)
```

Which is now the right way to create a searchQuery / searchFilter?

Current (Deprecated) Code:

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.query.BooleanQuery;
import com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.searchfilter.SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter;

....

ContentSearch search = new ContentSearch(BooleanQuery.composeAndQuery(allQueries), RELEVANCE_SORT, SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter.getInstance(), 0, 1);
```

How can this be done with the Confluence 8.0 API?

Edit:
We are developing a Plugin and the corresponding 8.0 classes from the docs
SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter, SiteSearchPermissionsQuery are marked as Internal (not for plugin use)

Answer (score 0):

I think, here is the best answer provided by a Atlassian staff member:
https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/broken-java-api-in-confluence-8-eap-contentsearch-getbyid-etc/62907/8

Summary: `SearchFilter` is replaced with `SearchQuery` and
`SiteSearchPermissionsSearchFilter` by [`SiteSearchPermissionsQuery`](https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/javadoc/8.0.2/com/atlassian/confluence/impl/search/v2/SiteSearchPermissionsQuery.html).

Comment: Thx for the answer. Been there already. Problem is, the mentioned classes are marked as Internal and are not for plugin use.

Comment: @Gobliins I did not confirmed it but there is somebody who claims that `@Internal` is not a problem: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/broken-java-api-in-confluence-8-eap-contentsearch-getbyid-etc/62907/15?u=krzysztofbogdan1

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not really helping … Even Atlassian stuff in their own support forum can't give a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/replacement-for-searchfilter-permissions-in-confluence-8-0-api/68147/3) worked for me (so no credits for me)

Basic code:

```
    private final SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory siteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory;


    public YourService(@ComponentImport SiteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory siteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory) {
        this.siteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory = siteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory;
    }

    ...
 
    Set<SearchQuery> queries = new HashSet<>();

    queries.add(siteSearchPermissionsQueryFactory.create());

    SearchQuery query = BooleanQuery.composeAndQuery(queries);

    ...
```